# Cómo puedo desarrollar una solución para extraer un xml de la url del Banco Central Europeo (ECB)

Tags: php, xml, base-de-datos

¿Cómo puedo desarrollar una solución para extraer un xml de la url del Banco Central Europeo (ECB) para hacer el intercambio de monedas.

Quiero generar en PHP una lista de tipo de cambio de moneda y luego a través de webservice a una tabla de base de datos

Origen XML: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
        <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
            <gesmes:Sender>
                <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
            </gesmes:Sender>
        <Cube>
            <Cube time="2017-08-04">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1868"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="130.67"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
            <Cube currency="CZK" rate="26.068"/>
            <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4388"/>
            <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.9028"/>
            <Cube currency="HUF" rate="304.36"/>
            <Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.241"/>
            <Cube currency="RON" rate="4.5635"/>
            <Cube currency="SEK" rate="9.6053"/>
            <Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.1494"/>
            <Cube currency="NOK" rate="9.3618"/>
            <Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.407"/>
            <Cube currency="RUB" rate="71.4691"/>
            <Cube currency="TRY" rate="4.1903"/>
            <Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.4888"/>
            <Cube currency="BRL" rate="3.6911"/>
            <Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.492"/>
            <Cube currency="CNY" rate="7.9757"/>
            <Cube currency="HKD" rate="9.2782"/>
            <Cube currency="IDR" rate="15791.56"/>
            <Cube currency="ILS" rate="4.2939"/>
            <Cube currency="INR" rate="75.5035"/>
            <Cube currency="KRW" rate="1334.12"/>
            <Cube currency="MXN" rate="21.1344"/>
            <Cube currency="MYR" rate="5.0777"/>
            <Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.5928"/>
            <Cube currency="PHP" rate="59.588"/>
            <Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.6097"/>
            <Cube currency="THB" rate="39.455"/>
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="15.8267"/>
        </Cube>
    </gesmes:Envelope>`

El programa PHP es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Christopher, bienvenido a SOes. Te sugiero que leas [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor aceptadas por la comunidad. No es recomendable colocar el código en una imagen por el hecho de que si llega a pasar algo con el hosting la pregunta quedaría sin el código y por tanto va a ser menos entendible. Al colocar el código fuente como texto nos aseguramos que permanezca intacto en un futuro.

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones Matias. Me asegurare de leerlas Saludos!